# GTK+ user interface testing

Tags: c, testing, gtk

I have created a user interface using GTK+ and C. I was wondering if there are any testing frameworks for testing this interface, similar to how selenium (a software testing framework for web applications) can be used for testing the interfaces of web applications. I want to create some regression tests for my GTK+ interface. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [dogtail](https://fedorahosted.org/dogtail/).

Comment: Your link is dead

Comment: this might be the repo for it: https://gitlab.com/dogtail/dogtail/

Answer (score 3):

I know it has been answered already. However ...

Dogtail is very usefull, however Dogtail isn't a `unittest framework`. From it's own description:

> dogtail is a GUI test tool and automation framework written in ​Python. It uses Accessibility (a11y) technologies to communicate with desktop applications. dogtail scripts are written in Python and executed like any other Python program.

If you want to unit test your GTK applications you should look at [GLIB TESTING. A unit testing framework for GLIB  written in C for C applications](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Testing.html).

Comment: GLib testing is for GLib applications, that can be completely unrelated to gtk. I don't see any tool for graphical interfaces in GLib Testing reference page.

Comment: Maybe just take a look into Google Test for C++ testing (Gtkmm apps).